# Failed to preview report

Tags: windows, permissions, service, reporting, windows-server-2008

I have a reporting services server environment in a windows server 2008 R2 .
I am developing in windows 7 using report builder 3. 
I am able to load and save the reports but not to preview them.
I'm getting this message: Failed to preview report... insufficient privilege to user "P423432\Steven". 
In the configuration roles in reporting server, the user that I use for developing has  all the permissions checked.
What could be happening with it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: anyone knows something about it? I'm getting crazy!

Answer (score 1):

The credentials look like you PC account credentials.  If you are in an AD domain, the credentials should be "domain\steven" where domain is your AD domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Its not the solution because the credentials are right. Remember I can load the reports, and even save. Its something more about autorization, But I dont know What.  Steven.

Comment: Take a look at the IIS logs for entries regarding the reportingserver URL.  Perhaps that will give you a lead.